# What is the first step in auditing the security efficiency of a simple website?

Tags: penetration-test, web-scanners

I am asked to write a first technical audit about the security best practices to improve a PHP web-site security.

I am wondering from where to start? Is there a famous audit forms to analyze and evaluate the security of a website? An online free tool to make the first check?

The website in question is a very basic one developed in PHP.

Comment: This is my first post in IT-Security. I can edit it as much as you ask !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the [OWASP Top 10 Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Top_Ten_Project).

OWASP has the best set of resources available online when it comes to web applications. You can learn plenty of information from there.

In addition, I would look into hardening the servers which your application run on. [CIS](http://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/en-us/?route=default) has a good set of benchmarks you could base your audit upon.

As far as tools go - recommendations are beyond the scope of the site. There are far too many out there. The [BackTrack](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/) distribution comes with many great ones. It can be quite confusing for a beginner though.

Comment: excellent , it seems a very good start.

Answer (score 2):

As Terry suggested OWASP is the first place anyone should start off especially w.r.t. Web App Security. In addition to that, I would suggest you to also look into [WASCv2](http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246978/Threat%20Classification) and S[ANS CWE Top 25](http://cwe.mitre.org/top25/).

Answer (score 0):

Extending the OWASP theme... OWASP highlights a top 10 of issues to be concerned with:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project

As well as the top 10 it is worth reflecting on the attack surface you are managing:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Attack_Surface_Analysis_Cheat_Sheet

One of the OWASP tools, Zap (Zed), helps spider your site looking for trouble and is a useful starting point in terms of automating your audit.

In terms of efficiency, you might wish to consider mean time to patch as a metric to report on.